# Multiple monitors with Kivy

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I'm looking at using Kivy to create a program that needs to display a window on each monitor, is there a way to accomplish this? I'd also prefer not to have a single window spanning across.

If not, is there another (good looking, windows/linux) GUI toolkit that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have two separate windows running two separate kivy apps controlling/communicating with each other via osc/twisted/... However one "App" instance is only limited to one App window for that process. It can launch another process(subprocess.popen) which has a new window though.

Comment: Indeed this is the only option as the docs for Window specify clearly: "Kivy supports only one window per application: please don’t try to create more than one."