# Running multiple Kivy apps at same time that communicate with each other

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, kivy

I would like my Kivy application to be able to spawn multiple apps (i.e. new windows) on a Windows machine that can communicate with each other.

[ScreenManager](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html) and [Popup](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.popup.html) options will not cut it because they live in the same window..I need to be able to drag new screens across multiple monitors and therefore need multiple windows.

Kivy docs explicitly state that ["Kivy supports only one window
per application: please don't try to create more than one."](http://kivy.org/docs/_modules/kivy/core/window.html)

A google search produces [this simple approach](https://github.com/Solecist/Multiple-Windows--Kivy-1.8.0) of simple spawning a new app from within another app, like so:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class ChildApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Child')


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        b = Button(text='Launch Child App')
        b.bind(on_press=self.launchChild)
        return b

    def launchChild(self, button):
        ChildApp().run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

However, when I do this, it launches the app within the same window and crashes, and my terminal spits out like crazy:

```
Original exception was:
Error in sys.exceptionhook:
```

I get the same result if instead of `ChildApp().run()` I do `multiprocessing.Process(target=ChildApp().run()).start()`

Using the `subprocess` library gets me closer to what I want:

```
# filename: test2.py

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class ChildApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Child')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ChildApp().run()
```

---

```
# filename: test.py

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

import subprocess


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        b = Button(text='Launch Child App')
        b.bind(on_press=self.launchChild)
        return b

    def launchChild(self, button):
        subprocess.call('ipython test2.py', shell=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

This spawns the child window without error, however now the main window is locked (white canvas) and if I close the child window, it just gets reopened.

They need to be able pass data between one another. Any ideas on how to do this correctly in Windows? This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178570/multiple-monitors-with-kivy) seems to suggest that this is possible but I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bj0's answer regarding subprocess was correct.

Even better, I figured out how to do this via multiprocessing, which allows better communication and passing of information between apps. It wasn't working before because I did `multiprocessing.Process(target=ChildApp().run()).start()` when it should be `multiprocessing.Process(target=ChildApp().run).start()`. The following works

```
# filename: test.py

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

from test2 import ChildApp

import multiprocessing


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        b = Button(text='Launch Child App')
        b.bind(on_press=self.launchChild)
        return b

    def launchChild(self, button):
        app = ChildApp()
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=app.run)
        p.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

---

```
# filename: test2.py

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class ChildApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Child')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ChildApp().run()
```

Comment: Maybe it's Python 3.4 or maybe it's OS X but I can confirm that under those conditions this does not work.

Comment: Hi, i'm getting an `EOFError : Ran out of input` from running the above two scripts, have any idea why?

Answer (score 5):

I tried baconwichsand's code and can confirm with Python 3.6 and Windows 10 it does not work. Apparently only top level object classes can be pickled, and since both apps inherit from the App class python throws an error. However a top level definition that simply executes the ChildApp().run() command can be pickled and works. Here is my working code.

```
import multiprocessing
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Main App Window')

class OtherApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Other App Window')

def open_parent():
    MainApp().run()

def open_child():
    OtherApp().run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = multiprocessing.Process(target=open_parent)
    b = multiprocessing.Process(target=open_child)
    a.start()
    b.start()
```

And here is the code I am using, including the Builder to use a shared .kv file for both windows.

```
import multiprocessing
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MainRoot(Widget):
    pass

class OtherRoot(Widget):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file('B:\Python_Codes\Testing Grounds\shared.kv')
        main = MainRoot()
        return main

class OtherApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file('B:\Python_Codes\Testing Grounds\shared.kv')
        other = OtherRoot()
        return other

def open_parent():
    MainApp().run()

def open_child():
    OtherApp().run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = multiprocessing.Process(target=open_parent)
    b = multiprocessing.Process(target=open_child)
    a.start()
    b.start()
```

Comment: It does not work for me on Ubuntu Focal with Kivy 2.0.0rc2 and Python 3.8.5. The main window sometimes becomes black while moving and freezes.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why it doesn't work with multiprocessing (I've never tried it), but it should at least work with `subprocess`.  The reason your main window is locked is because `subprocess.call` blocks the thread that calls it while it waits for the subprocess to finish and return a result.

You want to use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) instead, which does not block.

Answer (score 0):

Working on Ubuntu Python 3.10

Calling a subprocess in a multiprocess.

main.py

```
import multiprocessing
import subprocess
import shlex  
  
#my kivy code..

def sub_window():
    subprocess.call(shlex.split('python3 test.py'))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = multiprocessing.Process(target=sub_window)
    b.start()
    MyApp().run()
```

test.py

```
#another kivy app script..
OtherApp().run()
```