# Python Kivy PicklingError within event handler: Can't pickle <type 'code'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.code failed

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I'm new to both Kivy and multiprocessing.

I'm exploring running multiple Kivy Apps at the same time, using multiprocessing, in the same way as in: [Running multiple Kivy apps at same time that communicate with each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458331/running-multiple-kivy-apps-at-same-time-that-communicate-with-each-other).

Now, I want to maintain a shared list of the Apps currently running, for example with `Manager.list()` but I got stuck at the start. I've got a test code like that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

from multiprocessing import Process, Manager


class ParentApp(App):
    def __init__(self, app_list, **kwargs):
        super(ParentApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.app_list = app_list

    def build(self):
        self.add_self_to_list()
        return Label(text = "abc")

#   def on_start(self):
#       self.add_self_to_list()

    def add_self_to_list(self):
        self.app_list.append(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = Manager()
    my_list = manager.list()

    print "Before:"
    print my_list

    parent = ParentApp(my_list)

    p = Process(target = parent.run)
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print "After:"
    print my_list
```

This adds the `ParentApp` to the shared `my_list` correctly, but when I comment out the `self.add_self_to_list()` in `build`, and uncomment `on_start`, I get this PicklingError:

```
...
self.app_list.append(self)
File "<string>", line 2, in append
File "C:\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x64\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 758, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'code'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.code failed
```

I've also tried hooking `add_self_to_list` to the `on_press` callback of a Button, and I got the same error. Why does it work on the `build` method and not on callbacks? Is there any way around this?

I'm running Kivy 1.9.0 and Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

(In case you're wondering why I'm trying this way: each App can potentially call other Apps. If an App is already running, I don't want to start a new one and pollute the screen with copies of the same window. Ideally I would get hold of the App and pop its window in the front. I haven't had a go with Kivy App's root_window yet, so I'm not even sure if that is possible. Just looking into the options here :)  If you know already if this can or can't be done with Kivy, I'd also like to know, but maybe I'll post another question! )

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `kivy` has any special restrictions, but you can't pickle a `code` object for use in `multiprocessing`.  However, there is a fork of `multiprocessing` (called `multiprocess`) that uses a serializer (`dill`) that can pickle `code` objects.  So, `multiprocess` should have a chance of working for you.

```
>>> import multiprocess
>>> CodeType = compile('','','exec')
>>> f = lambda x:CodeType
>>> p = multiprocess.Pool()
>>> p.map(f, range(2))
[<code object <module> at 0x100aeb5b0, file "", line 1>, <code object <module> at 0x100af1130, file "", line 1>]
```

On a side note, I'd recommend not pickling a GUI class instance, but instead extracting and dumping the state from the GUI instead.

Comment: Note, I'm the author of `multiprocess`.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I just saw your answer now. I'll have a go as soon as I can, and come back to you.